# How do you export Drupal books to PDF?

Tags: drupal, pdf, drupal-modules, publish

I want to create a book using the Drupal book module and then export that entire book as a single PDF (all individual nodes merged into a single document). I want to have control of the formatting of that document. I also want the ability to have attachments linked from the resulting PDF document and to have those attachments distributed with the PDF.

Ive had bad experiences with unsupported or kludgy moduules in the past so I want to know the best way of doing this. I can see the following options:

- The book module itself seems to provide PDF export
- There is the [print module](http://drupal.org/project/print)

I haven't uncovered any other solutions yet.

Answer (score 0):

try this http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/book#comment-1922772

I think its the best option for you.

alternatively try this:

1) Make a view and get the output as per your filter criteria.
2) Use http://drupal.org/project/views_pdf and then save it as a pdf.

Cheers,
Vishal